# Verificar numero no banco de dados

Tags: java, banco-de-dados

Em meu banco de dados eu tenho uma tabela chamada "Matrizes". Nessa tabela eu faço o registro das matrizes de gado que possuo na fazenda, e cada matriz tem o seu respectivo número, que fica guardado na coluna "Numero" da tabela. Esta coluna é UNIQUE no banco de dados, então se eu tento salvar uma nova matriz com o número já existente, ele não salva.
Eu estava procurando uma maneira de deixar o meu sistema mais eficiente, fazendo com que assim que eu digitasse o numero para cadastrar uma nova matriz, ele fizesse uma busca no meu banco de dados e caso retornasse algum valor, bloqueia o cadastro, e caso não retorne nenhum valor, deixa prosseguir com o cadastro da matriz.

Edit: Criei esse código:

```
 private void txtnumeroFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                    
   MatrizesDAO dao = new MatrizesDAO();
   if(dao.verificarNumero(evt.getComponent().toString())){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.rootPane, "Numero já cadastrado");
      } else {
    }
}
```

mas está dando o erro

> Incompatible types: void cannot be converted to boolean

Comment: esse campo deveria ser de Auto Increment nao ?

Comment: Heitor, sua aplicação é web ou desktop?

Comment: A aplicação é desktop

Comment: Luís, o campo não poder ser Auto Increment, pois o número sou eu quem devo escolher.

Comment: Heitor essa ultima edição sua parece uma tentativa de resposta. Reverti removendo o post mas você pode postar resposta no campo "Publique uma resposta" ao inves de postar como edição da pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui fazer funcionar, não sei se da maneira correta. Segue o código:

Código DAO

```
public List<Matrizes> verificarNumero(String numero) {
    try {
        List<Matrizes> lista = new ArrayList<Matrizes>();

        String cmdSql = "SELECT * FROM matrizes WHERE numero LIKE ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = conecta.prepareStatement(cmdSql);
        stmt.setString(1, numero);

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        if (rs != null) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                Matrizes n = new Matrizes();
                n.setNumero(rs.getString("numero"));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Numero de Matriz já cadastrado");
                NovaMatriz.txtnumero.grabFocus();
                lista.add(n);
            }
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        return lista;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Código TextField

```
 private void txtnumeroFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                    
    MatrizesDAO dao = new MatrizesDAO();
    String numero = txtnumero.getText();
    List<Matrizes> lista = dao.verificarNumero(numero);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simples de se fazer isso é utilizar um tratamento de erro, utilizando um try catch e, caso ocorra algum erro notificar o usuário, mas se o requisito é verificar isso enquanto o usuário está editando, talvez um FocusListener sirva:

```
field.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        verificaValorExistenteNoBanco(e.getComponent().getText());
    }
});
```

Edit:
Durante a criação da sua tela, assim que você adicionar o campo onde o usuário digita esse número adiciona esse focus listener...

```
field.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        if(dao.verificaValorExistenteNoBanco(e.getComponent().getText())) {
            JOptioPane.showMessage(...);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Entendi a parte ai do FocusListener, mas qual seria o comando que eu usaria para verificar esse valor no banco e depois como eu faço pra ele me dar a mensagem que o numero já existe ou simplesmente deixar eu realizar o cadastro?

Comment: Eu faria o mesmo dentro da classe DAO?

Comment: Basta fazer uma consulta (um select) na base de dados usando esse atributo como filtro (select * com tabela where numero = 'meu valor')... Caso retorne algum resultado quer dizer que já existe registro com esse calor, caso contrário você pode seguir normalmente...

Comment: Mas no caso, eu queria que surgisse uma JOptionPane dizendo que o numero já existe. Teria como montar um exemplo pra mim?

Comment: Se você tem um Dao você sempre agrega todas as funções de acesso ao banco de dados nas classes Dao... Então essa validação durante o preenchimento seria feito por ele...  Já sobre o outro método que comentei, seu método de salvamento lançaria uma exceção (o seu objeto pode até tratar a exceção a nível de tentar novamente ou acrescentar mais informações, mas se sua aplicação possui interface com usuário é sempre melhor que a camada mais externa - a que controla a view - trate as exceções) e então à sua interface de usuário exibirá uma mensagem ajudando do problema...

Comment: Então cara, eu tentei aqui e ta erro na parte do "if". acho que é por causa do meu DAO... Tem como mandar um exemplo do DAO?

Answer (score -1):

Você poderá implementar esse requisito da seguinte maneira:
No seu campo de texto adicionar um evento para capturar a perda de foco (Exemplo [aqui](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ValidateavalueonthelostFocusevent.htm) e documentação [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html))
Ou adicionar uma customização do campo de texto para suportar o autocomplete
(Exemplos [aqui](http://minskytecharena.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/java-swing-autocomplete-textfield-with.html))

Comment: Esses links podem ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo dos links já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)